# What is "always" constituent of?

Tags: syntax, english, constituents

In the following sentence:

> People's opinions are not always the result of their experiences.

What is "always" constituent of?

I tried movement:

1. Not always, people's opinions are the result of their experiences. - sounds grammatical to me.
2. Always, people's opinions are not the result of their experiences. - sounds ungrammatical.
3. The results of their experiences, people's opinions are not always. - sounds ungrammatical.
4. Always the results of their experiences, people's opinions are not. -sounds grammatical to me.
5. People's opinions might not always be the result of their experiences.
6. People's opinions are sometimes the result of their experiences.

I am confused whether it is part of the NP "the result of their experiences"?

If you can give syntactic tests to show your arguments would be great. Thank you.

The sentences 5 and 6 were added after the question was asked and answered because I came up with additional examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first test is correct: The adverb "always" is - together with the negation "not" which modifies (negates) it - a constituent serving to modify the verb phrase (the being a result is modified w.r.t. time, namely that it is "not always" being one).
Since the head of the constituent is the adverb "always", most syntacticians would call this constituent an **adverbial phrase** and locate it as an adjunction to the verb phrase.
4. sounds very weird to me; I'm not a native speaker though. Looks like the part starting with "always" was topicalised, i.e. moved to the front of the sentence to make it the sentence's [topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topic_and_comment) (where the "not" is in [focus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focus_(linguistics))). Might be that this information structuring legitimates such a construction, but it is at least very marked I'd say, since the adverb ("always") was detached from its negation ("not"), making it hard to reconstruct the constituent.

Comment: I can interpret "not always' as a complex specifier for the VP. The fourth sentence is not very common but I've seen it being used to emphasize. Another alternative would be: The result of their experiences, people's opinions are not always.

Comment: Are you sure you mean a specifier as defined in X-bar theory? Such adverbial modifications are usually simply adjunctions. About the second sentence: Yes, sounds reasonable. The emphasis is a slightly different one though (here, the topic is the results, and the comment is that they are not always such; whereas in your sentence 4., "always" is part of the topic and, in the comment (the part after the comment), negated that this "always" quantification holds).

Comment: You are right. I just drew the three and it is an adjunct. For the rest it looks like a bit of semantic mixed with syntax. I agree that the first sentence sounds best and justifies always as being an adjunct of the VP that has been topizalised.

Comment: English syntax always messes with semantics :) Just compare the two readings in the sentence "All women didn't sing": The negation can either have scope over the singing, meaning "There was no woman who sang, but also over the "all" quantification, meaning" Not all woman sang", where "didn*t" is syntactically kind of in the wrong place to semantically modify the "all" - again an instance of focus-topic-strucuring ("all women" is the topic, "didn't" is in focus).

Comment: Thanks. I added a fifth sentences which definitely shows that "not always" is a constituent and modifies the verb. Also, I think the third sentences might be grammatically correct although unusual.